# no se me rellena el el div por la izquierda

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, grid, bootstrap-5

uso bootstrap e hice una row y en ella meti el col-12 que solo tengo un texto y una clase que me rellena de un color especifico la columna, pero me deja un hueco a la izquierda y no se porque. Es en la FILA TOTAL. le tengo comentado

```css
.rellenoColor {
    background-color: rgba(242, 249, 255, 1);
    margin-left: 0em;
}

.cajaSombra {
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 1px rgba(3, 1, 32, 0.3);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- FILA | Total -->
<section class="row gx-5 mb-5">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <h4 class="mt-3 mb-0">Datos de facturacion</h4>
                <hr class="m-0">
                <!-- Nombre -->
                <div class="col-12 mt-3 p-1 cajaSombra">
                    <span>Nombre:</span>
                </div>
                <!-- Texto informativo precios-->
                <div class="col-12 mt-1">
                    <small>Una vez realizado el pago podra descargar su factura</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--PAGO-->
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 cajaSombra">
                <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                    <h4 class="mt-3 mb-0">Pago</h4>
                <hr class="m-0">
                </div>
                <!-- FILA | Total -->
                    <div class="col-12 rellenoColor mt-3">
                        <!-- Unica columna -->
                        <span>Total: 583€</span>
                    </div>
                <!-- FILA | Politicas de privacidad -->
                <div class="col-12 mt-2">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="privacidad" id="privacidad">
                    <label for="privacidad">Acepto las politicas de privacidad</label>
                </div>
                <!-- FILA | Condiciones de uso -->
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="condiciones" id="condiciones">
                    <label for="condiciones">Acepto las condiciones de uso</label>
                </div>
                <!-- FILA | Boton de pagar -->
                <div class="col-12 my-3">
                    <button class="buttonBlue px-4"><i class="bi bi-paypal pe-1"></i><em>Pagar</em></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Creo que tienes echo un lio con las columnas el **col-12** es para que sea una columna de 12 en cualquiera resolución. En cambio los **col-md-6** es para una resolución en concreto. En este link veras para que resolución es cada clase, el **xs, sm, md, lg, etc...**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#responsive-utilities-tests

Comment: Tú mismo le has indicado que tenga ese margen a la izquierda... `<section class="row gx-5 mb-5">`, gx: [gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/) horizontales. Es decir, "espaciado" horizontal entre las diferentes columnas. Lo que hace basicamente es añadir padding, si pruebas a eliminar el `gx-5` verás que tu div ya se colorea entero (aunque rompe otras cosas, obviamente). Una solución puede ser añadir `g-0` (elimina los *gutters*) al div `cajaSombra` (div padre) y luego setearle los padding a los demás hijos a mano.